# Getting a segmentation fault trying to pass a node

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm new to C and I just started learning how to use pointers. I'm trying to create a function (r) that adds to a bst depending on if the parameter (int n) is greater than the root nodes value. However, I keep getting segmentation fault (core dumped) after running the following code. How do I fix it so that it can run normally without error.

```
struct node  {
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    }node;

struct node* newNode(int data){
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return (node);
    }

void r (int n, struct node* root);

int main() {

    struct node *root = newNode(1);
    printf("%d", root->data);
    r(10, root);
    return 0;
    }

void r(int n, struct node* root){
    if(n > root->left->data){
       root->right = newNode(n);
       printf("New right is: %d\n", root->right->data);
    }
    else if(n < root->left->data){
       int a = root->left->data;
       root->left->data = n;
       root->right->data = a;
       printf("New left is: %d\n", root->left->data);

    }

       return;
    }
```

Comment: The very first time you call `r(10, root)` you have `if (n > root->left->data)..` In this case `root->left` is NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `r` function you wrote:

```
root->left->data
```

But `root->left` is equal to `NULL`. This will cause a segfault because you can't dereference a null pointer.

You can check for validity by doing something like:

```
// Make sure the left node exists, then do the test after
if (root->left && root->left->data > n)
```

since doing `root->left` will cause it to check that it's non-zero (meaning not `NULL`).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks I cant believe I didnt notice that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CrisManrique Is there a way my answer could be improved? Or is it unacceptable in any way?

Comment: No, you were right, I had actually overlooked a simple mistake. You were right on the money. Sorry if I sounded sarcastic.

Comment: @CrisManrique Is there any way I can make this answer better?

Comment: @CrisManrique If this answer helped you, please [mark it as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).